# Google drive files preview api

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I want to display previews of the files (images, videos, docs, xl, ppt, pdf) stored on the google drive on a webpage. Which api or library  should I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanent links to thumbnails in Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648388/permanent-links-to-thumbnails-in-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 1):

with the google drive api, you can get the file's metadata via the 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/YourFileID 
request. Then parse the JSON response and use the thumbnailLink in the file info

Comment: This should be the correct answer. But I am not sure what exactly wanted to achieve @user1288043. Thumbnail is only first page and if contains text it is not readable.

Comment: Man, you're a lifesaver :) This should be the correct answer. For those looking to achieve this inside Google Apps Script (DriveApp), here is the ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getThumbnail()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Documents List API, displaying thumbnails as a preview. Or you could download/export the files and generate the preview yourself.

Comment: Ali, sorry to add an off-topic comment, but care to weigh in on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825822/google-documents-list-api-python-documentation#comment14115347_10825822)? I think we'd prefer to avoid the [whole Facebook debacle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/130268).