# How to scale down image with ImgApp in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-forms

I would like to be able to scale an image (from a google form response) down before or after inserting it into my google doc. I've been trying to use the ImgApp library with the `.doResize()` method. But I'm not quite sure how it's supposed to work.

Here is what I've got currently. Have I resized the image from google form correctly?

```
var fileURL = photo;
var fileID = fileURL.substr(fileURL.search("=")+1);  //strip off text before id= in the URL
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
var imageR = ImgApp.doResize(fileID, 630)
image = imageR.blob;
```

Now the question is how do I insert the resized image?

below is my full script

```
function testAutoFillGoogleDocFromForm() {
  try {
    let row = { values: [ "time", "photo", "2/1/2022", "event", "name", "", "photoCap", "photoDesc" ]};
    autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(row);
    console.log("done");
    row = { values: [ "time", "photo", "1/1/2023", "event", "name", "", "photoCap", "photoDesc" ]};
    autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(row);
    console.log("done");
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) { //function to insert google form sheet responses from the linked google sheet to the google doc
  try {
    let timestamp = e.values[0];
    let photo = e.values[1];
    let date = new Date(e.values[2]);
    let event = e.values[3];
    let name = e.values[4];
    let photoCap = e.values[6];
    let photoDesc = e.values[7];

    var headingStyle = {};
    headingStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;

    try {
      var fileURL = photo;
      var fileID = fileURL.substr(fileURL.search("=")+1);  //strip off text before id= in the URL
      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
      var imageR = ImgApp.doResize(fileID, 630)
      image = imageR.blob;
    }
    catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

    var doc = DocumentApp.openById("1x3M2BWD3saQdnuygS8CPyd7KOVrxkYBOs6s9p8GbImQ") //inserts responses based on date
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let i = 0;
    while( i < body.getNumChildren() ) {
      let para = body.getChild(i);
      if( para.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ) {
        let j = 0;
        console.log("numchild = "+body.getNumChildren());
        while( j < para.getNumChildren() ) {
          let child = para.getChild(j);
          if( child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK ) {
            // get next paragraph and check date
            if( (i+1) >= body.getNumChildren() ) break; // in case there is a page break at the end of body
            para = body.getChild(i+1);
            let temp = new Date(para.asParagraph().getText());
            console.log(temp);
            if( temp > date ) {
              body.insertPageBreak(i++);
              body.insertParagraph(i++,date.toLocaleDateString()).setAttributes(headingStyle);
              body.insertParagraph(i++,event);
              body.insertParagraph(i++,'- ' + name);
              body.insertImage(i++, image);
              body.insertParagraph(i++,photoCap);
              body.insertParagraph(i++,photoDesc);
              return;
            }
          }
          j++;
        }
      }
      i++;
    }
    // if the date is latest just append a new page
    body.appendPageBreak();
    body.appendParagraph(date.toLocaleDateString()).setAttributes(headingStyle);
    body.appendParagraph(event);
    body.appendParagraph('- ' + name);
    body.appendImage(image);
    body.appendParagraph(photoCap);
    body.appendParagraph(photoDesc);
    body.in



  }

  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

}
```

Comment: [Edit] to link source code of `ImgApp`

Comment: As ImgApp library is not part of any of the tags included, please provide more details  about it. Is it a Google Apps Script library? Is it shared with anyone or is private library? What are the parameters required by `ImgApp.doResize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
var image = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
var imageR = ImgApp.doResize(fileID, 630)
image = imageR.blob;
```

Do

```
// get permanent link to thumbnail, via https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086/555121
// set `sz` to needed width in pixels
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w630&id='+fileID, {
  // authorize request with Apps Script credentials of current user
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
});
// get thumbnail blob
var image = res.getBlob();
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086/555121