# Google Drive uc?id= no longer works

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am trying to write code to get the direct urls of images in a public Google Drive folder and embed them. Until a few minutes ago everything has been working and using the uc? trick gives the raw image so I can embed it. However now it is sending a download, even when I use &export=view.

Here is my code:

```
key = "supersecretgooglecloudconsolekey"

import re
import requests

def get_raw_image_links(folder_link):
    # Extract folder id
    folder_id = re.findall(r"/folders/([^\s/]+)", folder_link)[0]

    # Google cloud console request to get links
    api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='{folder_id}'+in+parents+and+mimeType+contains+'image/'&key={key}"
    response = requests.get(api_url).json()

    raw_image_links = []

    # Iterate over the files and retrieve raw image links
    for file in response['files']:
        raw_link = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file['id']}"
        print(raw_link)
        raw_image_links.append(f'<a href="{raw_link}"> <img src="{raw_link}" /> </a>')

    return ''.join(raw_image_links)


folder_link = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/**********"
image_links = get_raw_image_links(folder_link)
```

For example, this works: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=15bwLlBuPc4O8LXwxjsBJe_ctyPl8Tll2

But this doesn't for some reason and instead sends a download: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Gz4YrH2tefSVxKRvv6gnqnY3tk0Obm0T

How do I fix this? Also, it would be helpful if anyone knows how to scrape the raw image link from the viewing page of the image itself https://drive.google.com/file/d/15bwLlBuPc4O8LXwxjsBJe_ctyPl8Tll2/view

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about changing the endpoint? When your showing script is modified, please modify `raw_link` as follows.

#### From:

```
raw_link = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file['id']}"
```

#### To:

```
raw_link = f"https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id={file['id']}&sz=w1000" # Please modify w1000 to your actual situation.
```

- By this change, the image files are converted to PNG format. I thought that this might be one of several solutions.
- From your question and showing script, I guessed that your folder of `folder_link = "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/**********"` might be publicly shared. In that case, I thought that the above modification might be able to be used.

#### Reference:

- [Permanent links to thumbnails in Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25648388)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot preview https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Gz4YrH2tefSVxKRvv6gnqnY3tk0Obm0T is related to the `HEIC` format, we can store `HEIC` files in Google Drive but we cannot preview them, unfortunately the feature is not included yet.

Here's the list of image files you can preview:
Image files (.JPEG, .PNG, .GIF, .BMP, .TIFF, .SVG). There's no option for us to preview `HEIC` image files, if you can spare the time, please consider submitting a [Feature idea](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en) for further enhancements to Google Drive.

#### Reference:

- [Files you can preview](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en#:%7E:text=Supported%20file%20types)