# Inserting images into a Google Sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've been having issues with inserting images from Google Drive into a Google sheet using google scripts. Sometimes it works perfectly but sometimes it throughs error - Exception: The blob was too large. The maximum blob size is 2MB. The maximum number of pixels is 1 million.

Even though the maximum file size is 400kbs in the drive. I'm not able to find a work around how to fix the pixel issue through script.

````
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet '" + sheetName + "' not found.");
    return;
  }

  var cellAddresses = ["A5", "A16", "A27", "A38", "A49", "A60", "A71", "A82", "A93", "A104", "A115", "A126", "A137", "A148", "A159"];
  var folderName = "SSTest";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  var imageFiles = folder.getFiles();

  // Get the sorted image names
  var sortedImageNames = [];
  while (imageFiles.hasNext()) {
    var imageFile = imageFiles.next();
    sortedImageNames.push(imageFile.getName());
  }
  sortedImageNames.sort();

  // Upload images in sorted order
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedImageNames.length && i < cellAddresses.length; i++) {
    var imageName = sortedImageNames[i];
    var imageFile = folder.getFilesByName(imageName).next();
    var blob = imageFile.getBlob();
    var cell = sheet.getRange(cellAddresses[i]);
    var image = sheet.insertImage(blob, cell.getColumn(), cell.getRow());
  }

  Logger.log("Uploaded and sorted images in '" + sheetName + "'.");
}```

I have tried couple of small thing which didn't work.
````

Answer (score 1):

In your showing script, how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sortedImageNames.length && i < cellAddresses.length; i++) {
  var imageName = sortedImageNames[i];
  var imageFile = folder.getFilesByName(imageName).next();
  var blob = imageFile.getBlob();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(cellAddresses[i]);
  var image = sheet.insertImage(blob, cell.getColumn(), cell.getRow());
}
```

#### To:

```
var headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }; // Added

for (var i = 0; i < sortedImageNames.length && i < cellAddresses.length; i++) {
  var imageName = sortedImageNames[i];
  var imageFile = folder.getFilesByName(imageName).next();

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w300&id=${imageFile.getId()}`, { headers }).getBlob(); // Modified

  var cell = sheet.getRange(cellAddresses[i]);
  var image = sheet.insertImage(blob, cell.getColumn(), cell.getRow());
}
```

- By this modification, the resized images are used. In this sample, the image width is changed to 300 pixels by `sz=w300`. Please modify this to your actual situation.
- The endpoint of `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w300&id=${imageFile.getId()}` is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086).