# How to insert image into Google slides with [Exception: The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt.] error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

### The error:

I am trying to insert images on Google Drive into Google slides using their file ID.

However, I found that for certain images, using either `insertImage` or `replaceWithImage` generates the [Exception: The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt.] error. The following is a small recreation of the problem.

```
function myfunction() {
  var deck = SlidesApp.openById("...");
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var template = slides[0];
  var currentSlide = template.duplicate();

  var imgId = "...";
  var logo = DriveApp.getFileById(imgId);

  try {
    currentSlide.insertImage(logo);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: ", err);
  }

}
```

I cannot find what is wrong with those particular images. They are less than 50MB in size, below 25 megapixels, and in png or jpeg format. Unfortunately I cannot attach the concerned images as they are private photos, and I have yet been able to find a free image that has the same issue. But I will be grateful if anyone gives me any advice on what to try.

### What I have tried

#### .getBlob()

I tried using `DriveApp.getFileById(imgId).getBlob();` instead of  `DriveApp.getFileById(imgId)`. But nothing changed.

#### editing extension vs online converter

I downloaded the photo of the apple from an [encyclopedia](https://the-snack-encyclopedia.fandom.com/wiki/Apple), which is originally in .webp format. I then tried two things:

1. I changed its extension from .webp to .jpg by simply editing the filename on my Macbook, and uploaded it to Google Drive. This .jpg generates the same exception.
2. I uploaded the .webp to an [online converter](https://ezgif.com/webp-to-jpg) and downloaded the .jpg file, then uploaded it to Google Drive. This .jpg does *not* generate the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `I tried using DriveApp.getFileById(imgId).getBlob(); instead of  DriveApp.getFileById(imgId). But nothing changed.`, if your file ID of `imgId` is the valid value and you can see your image on Google Drive, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the image is converted to PNG. And, the PNG image is put into Google slide.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var deck = SlidesApp.openById("...");
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var template = slides[0];
  var currentSlide = template.duplicate();

  var imgId = "...";
  var logo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id=${imgId}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob(); // The endpoint is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086

  try {
    currentSlide.insertImage(logo);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: ", err);
  }
}
```

- If you want to modify the size of the image, please modify `currentSlide.insertImage(logo)` to `currentSlide.insertImage(logo).setWidth(###).setHeight(###)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just able to test this after apps script being down for around 4 hours. This works perfectly! But I am a complete beginner and don't understand why. Could you please give me some keywords I can use to look it up?

Comment: @steak Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Could you please give me some keywords I can use to look it up?`, in your situation, from `I tried using DriveApp.getFileById(imgId).getBlob(); instead of  DriveApp.getFileById(imgId). But nothing changed.`, I guessed that the content type might be invalid for `insertImage`. So, I proposed to convert your image to PNG format using the endpoint of thumbnail. PNG can be used to `insertImage`. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! However, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertimageblobsource) for `insertImage` says that the image must be "either in PNG, JPEG, or GIF format", and when I edit the extension of the apple picture to .png (by editing the filename), it generated the same exception. I downloaded the photo created by your code above, and it seems to still be a JPEG image, except smaller, and upon clicking "Get info" (macbook) the "More info" section is completely empty. It's still a mystery but it works. Thanks a lot!