# Compress the Total size of PDF in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, compression, image-compression

I have a Form where a user can put in pictures. These pictures are added to a temp document using google drive.
This temp document is then transferred to a PDF file.
After that the PDF is sent in an e-mail.

Sometimes this attachment is too big for the email.
Is there a way to compress the PDF file ( blob) in size?
Or compress the image file sizes (the image is also a blob)?

image:

```
var blob   = DriveApp.getFileById(splitText[0]).getBlob();
body.appendImage(blob).setWidth(sizes).setHeight(sizes);
```

PDF

```
const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF); 
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName( info[2] + "---" +  "Opmeting");
```

Comment: Check out the [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) service. It has functions that support compression.

Comment: In your situation, how about reducing the image size? I think that `.setWidth(sizes).setHeight(sizes)` changes only the apparent image size instead of the actual image size. I guessed that this might be a modification point. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between the script of `image:` and the script of `PDF`. So, can you provide your whole script? First, I would like to correctly understand your current situation.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, 

The code is to big to just put in. 

Image: just adds an image from a google drive url. 
The image is added on a new line in a temp document. 

the PDF makes from that temp doc a blob. Then a PDF en renames it.

Comment: I think the question is missing relevant details and is currently not answerable. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't correctly imagine your whole script from your reply and question. So, by guessing your situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize. By the way, when you reply comment by adding `@` like `@username`, the user can notice your reply.

Comment: @Lars Dilweg Now, I added a simple sample case. Also, please confirm it. When the image size of the original image is reduced, the exported PDF file size is also reduced. I guessed that this situation might be useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `Image: just adds an image from a google drive url. The image is added on a new line in a temp document. the PDF makes from that temp doc a blob. Then a PDF en renames it.`, unfortunately, I cannot correctly imagine your whole script. But, if your showing script is included in your actual script, please test the following modification.

#### From:

```js
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(splitText[0]).getBlob();
body.appendImage(blob).setWidth(sizes).setHeight(sizes);
```

#### To:

From `var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(splitText[0]).getBlob();`, it supposes that `splitText[0]` is the file ID of your image file.

```js
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w512&id=${splitText[0]}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob(); // The endpoint is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086
body.appendImage(blob).setWidth(sizes).setHeight(sizes);
```

In this case, it supposes that the variable `sizes` has already been declared elsewhere.

Or, how about the following modification?

```js
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w${sizes}&id=${splitText[0]}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob(); // The endpoint is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086
body.appendImage(blob);
```

- By this modification, the size of the image file of `splitText[0]` is changed and put into the Document with `appendImage(blob)`. In this modification, the size of the image for putting into the Document is changed (reduced). I guessed that this might lead to a reduction in the size of the exported PDF file.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot correctly imagine your whole script. So, this is just my guess.

#### Sample case:

As a test case, I tested the following situation.

- A PNG image is put into a Google Document.
- The sample PNG image file has a size of 4,705,077 bytes and 1536 x 1536 pixels.
- The exported PDF data size is compared between the following 2 sample scripts.

The sample script for testing is as follows.

```js
function sample1() {
  const fileId = "###"; // PNG image file of 4,705,077 bytes and 1536 x 1536 pixels
  var size = 512;

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
  body.appendImage(blob).setWidth(size).setHeight(size);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  const pdfFileSize = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getBlob().getBytes().length;
  console.log(pdfFileSize); // 6413647
}
```

In this case, the exported PDF file size was 6,413,647 bytes.

```js
function sample2() {
  const fileId = "###"; // PNG image file of 4,705,077 bytes and 1536 x 1536 pixels
  var size = 512;

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w${size}&id=${fileId}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getAs(MimeType.JPEG);
  body.appendImage(blob);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  const pdfFileSize = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getBlob().getBytes().length;
  console.log(pdfFileSize); // 706321
}
```

In this case, the exported PDF file size was 706,321 bytes.

It is found that when the original image size is reduced, the exported PDF file size is also reduced. When `getAs(MimeType.JPEG)` is modified to `getBlob()`, the exported PDF file size is 725,079 bytes. If the original image format is JPEG format, the exported PDF file size was the same between `getAs(MimeType.JPEG)` and `getBlob()`. Because the mimeType of the image is not changed from JPEG.

I think that about `sample2`, when `size` is large, the exported PDF file size is also large.

Comment: @K J Thank you for replying. In my answer, I proposed to reduce the original image size when the image is put into Google Document. In your question, the large size image is put into Google Document and exported it as a PDF file. In this case, in the current stage, even when `setWidth` and `setHeight` are used, the exported PDF uses the original image. By this, when the original image size is large, the exported PDF file size is also large.

Comment: @K J From this situation, I proposed to put the small size image by reducing the original image size. By this, the exported PDF file size becomes small. Actually, in my test, the size of PDF file can be reduced by this approach. If my comment was not useful, please tell me.

Comment: @K J Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In my answer, in order to reduce the exported PDF file size, I proposed to reduce the original image size when the image is put into Google Document. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your reply and my answer to your original question. Can I ask you about the details of it? By the way, I thought that you wanted to reduce the exported PDF file size. Is my understanding correct? And, can you provide your actual expected result? If my answer was not useful for your situation, I can delete it.

Comment: @K J By the way, in my answer, I think one of several approaches. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: @K J Thank you for replying. About `@ Tanaike I am not the Questioner simply an observer explaining the consequence of size reduction can only be at the cost of lower quality.`, I couldn't notice it. I apologize for my poor English skill. About the reduction of the image size and the quality, I understand it. But, if a large image size is used, the reduction of the image size might be acceptable. So, I understand that this is one of several approaches. I deeply apologize for my poor skill and English skill again. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @K J Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether my approach is useful for the owner of this question. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: @K J Thank you for replying and for your concern. I believe that your comment is useful for both me and other users, and also it will help the owner of the question understand my proposed approach. And, I am a physicist and my field is not related to IT. But, in order to take advantage of scripting and APIs, I am always studying from a lot of users in Stackoverflow. I always appreciate them.