The thumbnail of a presentation is empty immediately after it is created, saved and closed
I create a presentation, insert an image into it, save and close it.
Using the Drive API I get a thumbnailLink, then a blob and from it I create a PNG file.
The problem is that the file is empty and does not contain the inserted image.
Here's the code:
function toPng() {
  const folderId = "###";
  const imageUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";

  var presentation = SlidesApp.create('Test');
  var prId = presentation.getId();
  // var prId = "#####";

  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  slide.insertImage(imageUrl);
  presentation.saveAndClose();
  // Utilities.sleep(60000);

  const thumbLink = Drive.Files.get(prId).thumbnailLink;
  const thumbnailURL = thumbLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s100");

  const pngBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(thumbnailURL).getBlob();
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  destinationFolder.createFile(pngBlob).setName('newFile.png');
}

If you comment out var prId = presentation.getId() and substitute the id of the previously created presentation var prId = "#####", then everything is fine, the image is in the file.
I assumed the problem was that the thumbnail takes a while to create.
I added Utilities.sleep(1000), increased the delay time to 2 minutes - it didn’t help.
I would be grateful for your ideas on how to solve this problem.

Although I'm not sure about your actual expected result, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful and that was different from your actual expected result, I apologize.

Good approach, thanks. When you tried my code, were you using version 2 of the Drive API? I do, since I was getting an error on ver.3.

Thank you for replying. About When you tried my code, were you using version 2 of the Drive API? I do, since I was getting an error on ver.3., in the case of Drive API v3, the default fields are small. So, if you want to retrieve thumbnailLink from Drive API v3, it is required to be const thumbLink = Drive.Files.get(prId, {fields: "thumbnailLink").thumbnailLink; or const thumbLink = Drive.Files.get(prId, {fields: "*").thumbnailLink;. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Yes, I did that, because in ver. 3 the method require the fields parameter. However, it is unclear why the Tumbnail is empty.

Thank you for replying. About However, it is unclear why the Tumbnail is empty., as I have already mentioned in my answer, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. So, I proposed a workaround in my answer. I apologize for this situation.

I will clarify. It is unclear why an object's tumbnail is empty when the tumbnaillink is retrieved within the code that created the object. After all, if an object is created outside of this code, the tumbnail is not empty.

Thank you for replying. About I will clarify. It is unclear why an object's tumblenail is empty when the tumblenaillink is retrieved within the code that created the object. After all, if an object is created outside of this code, the tumblenail is not empty., I got the same situation. But, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. But, in the Slides API, there is a method for retrieving the thumbnail. I'm not sure whether this is related to the above issue. So, I proposed a workaround for using it. I deeply apologize that I proposed a workaround.

I greatly appreciate your help. You are our lifesaver. Unfortunately, the workaround does not allow you to get different sizes, for example, the one stated in the post (=s100).

Thank you for replying. About Unfortunately, the workaround does not allow you to get different sizes, for example, the one stated in the post (=s100)., I couldn't notice that you wanted to variously adjust the image size. I apologize for this. So, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it.

I also came to the same solution - intermediate saving to a file. Unfortunately, the cause of the problem outlined in the post remains unclear. Thanks anyway, I accepted your answer.

Thank you for replying. As another approach, even when only Slides API is used, the valid thumbnail was not obtained from the created Google Slide. I guessed that the process of saving Google Slides might be different from Spreadsheet and Document. And, when I saw the method Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail, I thought that this might have been implemented to use instead of the thumbnail of Drive API because of the current issue in your question. For example, how about reporting it to the Google issue tracker?

I think this is a good idea. The only thing stopping me is that I already sent one bug report yesterday. Will they ban me for harassment.

I come up with another approach, just now. So, I added it. Please try it.

Great, this option works great too. And you don't need Slides API. Respect.

Thank you for replying and testing it again. Yes. In this case, the script can be worked without Slides API.

I had the same situation with you. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. But, at that time, when Slides API was used, I noticed that the thumbnail could be obtained. So, as the current workaround, how about using Slides API? When this is reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.
When you test this, please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services.
From:
const thumbLink = Drive.Files.get(prId).thumbnailLink;
const thumbnailURL = thumbLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s100");

To:
const thumbnailURL = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(prId, slide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.mimeType": "PNG", "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "SMALL" }).contentUrl;


The size can be selected from LARGE&, MEDIUM, and SMALL.

When I tested this modification, I obtained the following image.



Reference:

Method: presentations.pages.getThumbnail

Added 1
About the following reply,

Unfortunately, the workaround does not allow you to get different sizes, for example, the one stated in the post (=s100).

When my proposed workaround is used, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function toPng() {
  const folderId = "###";
  const imageUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";

  var presentation = SlidesApp.create('Test');
  var prId = presentation.getId();
  // var prId = "#####";

  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  slide.insertImage(imageUrl);
  presentation.saveAndClose();
  // Utilities.sleep(60000);

  // const thumbLink = Drive.Files.get(prId).thumbnailLink;
  // const thumbnailURL = thumbLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s100");

  const thumbnailURL = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(prId, slide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.mimeType": "PNG", "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "SMALL" }).contentUrl;
  const temp = DriveApp.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch(thumbnailURL).getBlob());
  const url = `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w100&id=${temp.getId()}`; // This endpoint is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504086
  const pngBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  Drive.Files.remove(temp.getId());

  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  destinationFolder.createFile(pngBlob).setName('newFile.png');
}

With this modification, when you can adjust the output image size by modifying w100.
Added 2:
As another approach, how about modifying as follows? I come up with another approach, just now. In this approach, the created file is copied. And, the thumbnail link is retrieved from the copied Google Slide. When I tested the following script, I confirmed that a valid thumbnail image could be obtained. Please test it.
function toPng() {
  const folderId = "###";
  const imageUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";

  var presentation = SlidesApp.create('Test');
  var prId = presentation.getId();
  // var prId = "#####";

  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  slide.insertImage(imageUrl);
  presentation.saveAndClose();
  // Utilities.sleep(60000);
  
  var temp = DriveApp.getFileById(prId).makeCopy("temp").getId();
  const thumbLink = Drive.Files.get(temp, { fields: "thumbnailLink" }).thumbnailLink;
  const thumbnailURL = thumbLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s100");
  const pngBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(thumbnailURL).getBlob();
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  destinationFolder.createFile(pngBlob).setName('newFile.png');
  Drive.Files.remove(temp);
}

